# Selenium DragnDrop not working properly

Tags: selenium

I am trying to moving a div with Selenium DragnDrop. Here is my Code

```
 WebElement fromElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("layoutDivPosition_locator"));
 WebElement toElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("layoutDivPosition_locator"));
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 Action dragnDrop = action.clickAndHold(fromElement).moveToElement(toElement).release(toElement).build();
 dragnDrop.perform();
```

Please help for this .

Comment: Can you post your URL?

Comment: Cant. Its an internal Portal. Is there any other way except this ?

Comment: Ok..you can post screen shot of the website and post html code,which is related drag and drop.

Comment: Your from and to element are having same xpath.shouldnt it be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium's actions for drag and drop do not play nice with HTML5, when you trying to move element to some frame and in several other situations. Possibly you can solve your problem using this jQuery solution:
[[C#][Selenium] How to drag-hover-drop an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279145/cselenium-how-to-drag-hover-drop-an-element)