# Connect two boxes with a line via drag and drop

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Selenium rookie here with a question regarding drag and drop.

I have two boxes and from one of the boxes i can drag a line and connect it to the other box.

I have tried various ways but none of them seem to work.

```
Actions action = new Action(driver);
action.dragAndDrop(box1 , box2).perform(); // Did not work

action.clickAndHold(box1).moveToElement(box2).release().perform(); //did not work either

action.clickAndHold(box).moveByOffset(coordonates of box2).release().perform(); // also did not work
```

This is were my knowledge of selenium stops , is there any other way i can do this?

I know the xpath is good because when i perform element.click(); it access it so its not that.

Comment: Try to use build() before performing the action. like action.dragAndDrop(box1 , box2).build().perform();..sometimes it may give problem.

Comment: Tried using .build() as well , still nothing.

Comment: Which URL r u using??

Answer (score -1):

Selenium's actions for drag and drop do not play nice with HTML5, when you trying to move element to some frame and in several other situations. Possibly you can solve your problem using this jQuery solution:
[[C#][Selenium] How to drag-hover-drop an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279145/cselenium-how-to-drag-hover-drop-an-element)